# Passing two values from awk to bash

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I have a list of value in which I am looking for the highest and the lowest value using `awk` inside of `bash`. I am able to find these, but I'm unable to assign the values to some variable so I can use them in `bash` later on.

My input:

```
number  location  length  value

 1        2         40     0.96
---       5         45     0.97
 4        5         47     0.96
---       5         35     0.95
 2        5         60     0.95
---       3         55     0.96
```

My `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR==1{max=$3; min=$3}{if ($3>max) max=$3; if ($3<min) min=$3;} END {print max,min}' List.txt
```

Output:
`60` and `35`.

I know it is possible to pass a value from `bash` to `awk` by declaring it in bash and again right at the beginning of my `awk` script with `-v`.

```
Variable1=string;
awk -v Variable1=$Variable '{}'
```

Is there a way to do the same thing, but from awk to bash so I can keep `min` and `max`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
read -r max min < <(awk 'NR==1{max=$3; min=$3}{if ($3>max) max=$3; if ($3<min) min=$3;} END {print max,min}' List.txt)
```

then:

```
echo $max
echo $min
```

OR:

```
arr=( $(awk 'NR==1{max=$3; min=$3}{if ($3>max) max=$3; if ($3<min) min=$3;} END {print max,min}' List.txt) )
```

then:

```
echo ${arr[0]} # max
echo ${arr[1]} # min
```

OR:

```
set -- $(awk 'NR==1{max=$3; min=$3}{if ($3>max) max=$3; if ($3<min) min=$3;} END {print max,min}' List.txt)
```

then:

```
max=$1
min=$2
```

Comment: Thanks! In the first one, does it depends on the order or it goes by the name?

Comment: It goes by name actually and names are used in the order of out awk's output.